# Can we get Code Review in the options to move a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration-path-request

There are instances where a question is more on-topic on Code Review.SE. However, the only way to get it migrated is to leave a custom message for a mod. Can we get Code Review added to the options to move a question?

Answer (score 5):

[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is still in Beta. <del>TPTB</del> The devs have said multiple times that they will not add a Beta site to the possible migration paths.

Continue flagging for Moderator attention.

Comment: Another advantage to this, in my opinion, is that it'll give others more time to learn what does and does not belong on CR.  We still receive bad migrations from time to time, even from other moderators.